# как сделать так чтобы данная функция заменяла сокращенные слова на их полный вариант. jq

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

например есть элемент со следующими классами:

```
<div class='font-size=50px margin-left=50px width=200px background-color=red'>hello world</div>
```

и есть следующая функция, которая получает свойства и значения из классов и применяет их на тот же элемент:

```js
function getProp(classStr) {
  return classStr.split('=')[0]
}

function getValues(classStr) {
  var values = classStr.split('=')[1]
  return values.split(',').join(' ')
}

function transform(el, prop, values) {
  $(el).css(prop, values)
}

var elements = $('div')
elements.each(function(i, el) {
  var classList = $(el).attr('class')
  if (!classList) return
  var classProps = classList.split(' ')
  $(classProps).each(function(i, str) {
    var prop = getProp(str)
    var values = getValues(str)
    transform(el, prop, values)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='font-size=50px margin-left=50px width=200px background-color=red'>hello world</div>
```

так вот... я хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было не писать полностью наименования свойств в классах, а заменить их на их сокращения, как: `fs=50px ml=50px w=200px bg-color=red` итд

как это возможно?

Comment: это возможно путем написания такого кода, который переводит короткие строки в длинные. Например, используя словарь.

Comment: создать объект, где ключ это полная версия свойства, а значение - сокращенное.

Comment: @Igor словарь.?

Comment: @MishaSaidov можете продемонстрировать, пожалуйста?

Comment: @MishaSaidov, наоборот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var slovar = {
  "fs": "font-size",
  "ml": "margin-left",
  "bg-color": "background-color"
};

function getFullName(shortName) {
  return slovar[shortName] || shortName;
}

console.log(getFullName("ml"),getFullName("bg-color"),getFullName("fs"),getFullName("margin-top"));

function transform(el, prop, values) {
  $(el).css(getFullName(prop), values)
}
```

Comment: ухтыы круто! но я все равно не могу сообразить как это применить в моем случае..

Comment: @valeria измените функцию `transform` - как в ответе

Comment: спасибо большое!